# Align 2 flex items - one to the left and one centered, but have the same baseline

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Here is a visualization:
[image]
The red needs to always stay in the left corner.
The green can grow or shrink, but it has to be always centered.
The green and red have to share the same baseline, i.e. regardless of red's height, green stays at the bottom.

I can make them stay on the baseline using `align-items`, but I can't figure out how to center the green without moving the red.
Red can't use `position: absolute` because then green can't find the baseline.

This is how I currently have it, but this moves `red` to the center, right next to green. However, if I do `justify-content: flex-start`, then I can't center green.

```
container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: baseline;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

red {
    max-width: 10%;
}


green {
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: Margin and: nth-child/last-child can help. You should post your HTML an CSS to demonstrate your issue . So one can efficiently help ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thanks, I added example code.

Comment: Can we also see your HTML structure ?

Comment: In flexbox-elements you can use `margin: 0 auto;` to center the green element. See example: [https://jsfiddle.net/74qgskzy/](https://jsfiddle.net/74qgskzy/)

Comment: ... here is an example of the idea ;)  https://jsfiddle.net/vL84wdun/

Comment: @Atomkind this centers green relative to the right edge of red. I want to center green relative to the container, not red.

Comment: @AnsisSpruģevics so just add position relative to container and absolute to red .. see [https://jsfiddle.net/v91fpg4q/](https://jsfiddle.net/v91fpg4q/)